# Linq to SQL ObjectContext in Web App - Thread Safety Concern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

Busy doing some work on an existing web app and concerned about the thread safety of the ObjectContext being used in a BaseRepository class. The code that is causing my spidey sense to tingle is:

```
   // within base repository
   private SiteDataContext context;

   public SitepDataContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (context == null)
                context = new SiteDataContext();
            return context;
        }
    }

    // inherited repository
public class InheritedRepository1 : BaseRepository
{
    public SomeEntity Get()
    {
        var something = Context.SomeEntity.First();
    }
}

 public class InheritedRepository2 : BaseRepository
{
    public SomeOtherEntity Get()
    {
        var something = Context.SomeOtherEntity.First();
    }
}
```

My understanding is:

1. the ObjectContext is **not** threadsafe and may be shared across threads in this instance.
2. A single objectcontext should be used across an http request. Multiple objectcontexts are being created from various repositories to render a page.
3. The objectcontext does not seem to be closed, disposed off at any point in the http request. This could be a problem if transactions are being used and transactions are committed from threads than did not begin them.

Would appreciate any feedback on **these 3 points above** as my experience is primarily based on NHibernate.

Comment: I guess if it is used in a web application, every request is made in a new thread. So in your controllers, you initiate a data context, and share across all the repositories which you need to use for the current controller action. I think it wouldn't cause any issue. This is my thought.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement the [Repository and Unit of Work](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know the patterns well. I am only adding to an existing code base and am more concerned about understanding the threading issues in the code I posted before I recommend a refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the IIS uses Thread pool to manage requests, my solution is to create one and only one ThreadStatic DataContext for each request, and clear it after request ending.

```
public class DataContextManager
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static MyDataContext dataContext = null;

    public static MyDataContext GetContext()
    {
        if (dataContext == null)
        {
        dataContext = new MyDataContext();
    }
    return dataContext;
}


public static void Clear()
{
    dataContext = null;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks Allen. I have worked with session per request patterns before. Are you saying that the code in the example i posted would not be thread safe?

Comment: the example code didn't show whether it is thread safe or not. It depends on BaseRepository. I just given you a suggestion that I am using. :)